# Is there a way to decouple controller method input names from ActionFilterAttribute actionArguments and RouteData.Values dictionaries?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, actionfilterattribute

I am running into this issue often and I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

I have APIControllers methods that have inputs e.g

```
[ProductDetailsValidation]
[HttpPost]
[Route("{productId}/details")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostProductDetails(
    [FromUri] string productId, 
    [FromBody] ProductDetails productDetails) 
{
    //...
}
```

And I have an action filter like this:

```
public class ProductDetailsValidationAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //coupled to productId variable name
        string productId = actionContext.ControllerContext
            .RouteData
            .Values["productId"].ToString(); 

        Dictionary<string,object> data = actionContext.ActionArguments;

        //coupled to productDetails variable name
        ProductDetails details = (ProductDetails)data["productDetails"]; 

        //...
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to decouple the names so renaming can happen without breaking the `ProductDetailsValidationAttribute`.

If there is no other way I wonder if it is possible to write a unit test that will trigger the `ProductDetailsValidationAttribute` with a mocked call to the `APIController` end-point. Of course I could have an integration test but that is not the point of the question.

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the action filter? Maybe you want to do something that you could solve otherwise?

Comment: @venerik validation of the inputs. Let's say that productId doesn't correspond to a product or some required property of productDetails wasn't passed etc.. So in the validation there are database calls etc. This is so the service code is clean and it doesn't have validation and authorization code.

Comment: In that case I would use `DataAnnotations` on `ProductDetails`. Then I'd create an `ActionFilter` that validates the `ModelState` and return some sort of `BadRequest` when `ModelState` is not valid. Checking the database should in my opinion not be a concern of an `ActionFilter` but of a business layer talking to a data access layer. 

But we are drifting away from your original question (to which I don't have an answer by the way).

Comment: @venerik the actionfilter is not doing the database calls itself but there is DAL service that does that. I understand what you are saying but I am not talking about field validation more id-consistency validation with the database. I also have authorization filters that have the same name coupling and those use a DAL service to talk with the database too.